# Telegram not to be found

Tags: 14.04, telegram

I have installed telegram many months ago and it was working fine. Today it wouldn't open from the launch or from startup and when I tried looking for it in the Ubuntu software centre it didn't seem to be among the insalled programs. I thought I needed to uninstall it first in order to try and reinstall it.
I'm using 14.04

Answer (score 0):

What I did was: delete the old telegram folder from the download one then downloaded again from the telegram web site and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You just need to update repositoy and libraries.
Didyou try: sudo dpkg --configure-a // sudo apt-get install -f

Or:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update-manager -d -c && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg -i --force-all %% sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

This things above not bite. But you are in charge. If you think is no good Do not do it. I Did and still alive.

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question and will probably lead to undesirable results for the OP.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I just reinstalled (the executable file was in the download folder)